# How to redirect to a maintenance page for applications running in a TomEE container?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, apache-tomee

I upgraded from a plain Apache web server to a *TomEE* application container. In Apache i used a `.htaccess` to redirect my pages when in maintenance. This could be on a remote server, and no restart was needed. Is this possible on TomEE